# Change arguments of a product of functions

Tags: pattern-matching

I am trying to do the following with rule-based pattern matching

```
(f1[t] f2[t] f3[t]) /. {x__ -> n[
     Product[x[[i, 0]][om[i]], {i, 3}]]} // Quiet
```

which gives me the output `n[f1[om[1]] f2[om[2]] f3[om[3]]]`. However, it seems as if one cannot specify parts of a pattern MMA gives the error messages

```
"Part specification x[[1,0]] is longer than depth of object"
```

I would like to do the operatoration for a product of `n` arbitrary functions `f1[t]`...`fn[t]` where the number of functions is automatically detected (I cannot use `Length[]` as well). How would one do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f1[t] f2[t] f3[t] /. Times[x_, y__] :> n[Times @@ MapIndexed[#[[0]][om[#2[[1]]]] &, {x, y}]]
```

> n[f1[om[1]] f2[om[2]] f3[om[3]]]

Also

```
Module[{i = 1}, f1[t] f2[t] f3[t] /. {t :> om[i++]} // n]
```

> n[f1[om[1]] f2[om[2]] f3[om[3]]]

**Update:** ***"If all the functions are equal"***:

```
Inactivate[f1[t] f1[t] f1[t]] /. 
 Inactive[Times][x_, y__] :> Activate@n[Times @@ MapIndexed[#[[0]][om[#2[[1]]]] &, {x, y}]]
```

> n[f1[om[1]] f1[om[2]] f1[om[3]]]

```
Activate@Module[{i = 1}, Inactivate[f1[t] f1[t] f1[t]] /. {t :> om[i++]} // n]
```

> n[f1[om[1]] f1[om[2]] f1[om[3]]]

**Update 2:** ***"... if one replaces e.g. f1[t] to become (x1[t]-x2[t])"***

The first method works if the level specification `{-2}` is used in `MapIndexed`:

```
Inactivate[f1[t] f2[t] f3[t]] /. Inactive[Times][x_, y__] :> 
   Activate@n[Times @@ MapIndexed[#[[0]][om[#2[[1]]]] &, {x, y}, {-2}]]
```

> n[f1[om[1]] f2[om[2]] f3[om[3]]]

```
Inactivate[f1[t] f1[t] f1[t]] /. Inactive[Times][x_, y__] :> 
  Activate@n[Times @@ MapIndexed[#[[0]][om[#2[[1]]]] &, {x, y}, {-2}]]
```

> n[f1[om[1]] f1[om[2]] f1[om[3]]]

```
Inactivate[(x1[t] - x2[t]) (x1[t] - x2[t]) (x1[t] - x2[t])] /. 
 Inactive[Times][x_, y__] :> 
  Activate@n[Times @@ MapIndexed[#[[0]][om[#2[[1]]]] &, {x, y}, {-2}]]
```

> n[(x1[om[1]] - x2[om[1]]) (x1[om[2]] - x2[om[2]]) (x1[om[3]] - x2[om[3]])]

The second method can also be modified (so that `ReplaceAll` is mapped onto the terms of the product) to work for all three cases:

```
Activate@Module[{i = 1}, n[With[{j = i++}, # /. t :> om[j]] & /@ 
    Inactivate[f1[t] f2[t] f3[t]]]]
```

> n[f1[om[1]] f2[om[2]] f3[om[3]]]

```
Activate@Module[{i = 1}, n[With[{j = i++}, # /. t :> om[j]] & /@ 
    Inactivate[f1[t] f1[t] f1[t]]]]
```

> n[f1[om[1]] f1[om[2]] f1[om[3]]]

```
Activate@Module[{i = 1}, n[With[{j = i++}, # /. t :> om[j]] & /@ 
    Inactivate[(x1[t] - x2[t]) (x1[t] - x2[t]) (x1[t] - x2[t])]]]
```

> n[(x1[om[1]] - x2[om[1]]) (x1[om[2]] - x2[om[2]]) (x1[om[3]] - x2[om[3]])]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works for `f1 != f2 != f3` but stops working if all the functions are equal.

Comment: @DisplayName, please see the update.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I lack a little bit of knowledge to come up with sth like this. I just read into pattern matching but it needs some time to settle. But I also like the approach with the `RuleDelayed`. The mathematical background of this question is to write a product in time domain as a product in Fourier space via the convolution theorem. `n[]` is then simply a functional involving integrations over the `om`s.

Comment: I think the code must be edited once more if one replaces e.g. `f1[t]` to become `(x1[t]-x2[t])`.

Comment: @DisplayName, please see update 2.

Comment: Thank you again! I think now all the cases are covered.

Answer (score 1):

A simple function can do it.

```
changeArg[p : Times[__], var_Symbol, head_Symbol] := 
  head[MapIndexed[#1[var[#2[[1]]]] &, Head /@ p]]

changeArg[f1[t] f2[t] f3[t], om, n]
```

> `n[f1[om[1]] f2[om[2]] f3[om[3]]]`

Comment: Thank you for another possible answer. I think in the current form it doesn't cover the case of equal functions.